# Detecting browser autofill before javascript getDocumentReady

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, autofill, floating-labels

I have a problem with my inputs, i had a custom floating label once there is text inside my input. My problem is chrome autofill add the text after my javascript onDocumentReady check for text. I want my javascript function to be called after chrome as loaded the text or any time of autocompletion. Is it possible?

I have tried launching the javascript function upon documentGetReady.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       toggleInputsFloatingLabelCustomClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a change function instead to see if any of your inputs change

```
jQuery('input').change(function(){
    toggleInputsFloatingLabelCustomClass();
}
```

this will solve your problem of chrome autofilling after your script has run

Answer (score 0):

You can add onkeyup definition for your inputs eq.

```
<input onkeyup='toggleInputsFloatingLabelCustomClassWithWait();'/>
```

than you can check if user is stil writing eq. Every one seocond and execute your method if user is writing like this:

```
var timeout = null;
function toggleInputsFloatingLabelCustomClassWithWait() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        toggleInputsFloatingLabelCustomClass();
    }, 1000);
}
```